# Convert Japanese Style English Font to Normal(?) English Font

Tags: loanwords

This might be computer science related question.

I am manipulating Japanese data and in some Japanese words, there are English words and Numbers are in.

ＳＹＳＫＥＮ, 松井ケ丘３, コメリＨ＆Ｇ, 篠路７－１ are the examples.

I see spacing between 'special characters', which are not Japanese/Kanji.
I am trying to find convert them to normal(I guess it does not look normal to Japanese) English like "SYSKEN, 松井ケ丘3, コメリH&G, 篠路7-1" but I cannot start to where.

What those fonts? or spacing rules are called in Japan or world wide?

Please guide me to solve my assginments :(

Answer (score 1):

halfwidth / fullwidth forms
this is the keyword and a starting point.

Sorry for bothering

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms